# UDK iOS ; base Class

Tags: ios, udk, mobile

I want to make a game with UDK for mobile and I wonder if There is any limits?

I mean, for example, can I use `UTPawn` as my base Pawn class when making a game for my mobile(iOS) game?

How can I know which classes are legal in my case?

Comment: I would suggest that if it compiles, it's OK. That said, without some extra info, there isn't much we can help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one month working on my iOS game, As Nate Bross said in comment, I understand that there is no special limitation and if my codes compile and work in mobile previewer, Everything will work in iDevice too.